# Login to web using TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How do I press the login button using `TWebBrowser` on the web page "https://v-tri.tri.co.id:8434/insms/dealer/en/loginin.do" using Delphi7 ?

```
procedure TForm1.Open_webClick(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  webbrowser1.Navigate('v-tri.tri.co.id:8434/insms/dealer/en/loginin.do'); 
end; 

procedure TForm1.InputClick(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('UserName').setAttribute('value', edit1.Text );
  WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('PassWord').setAttribute('value', edit2.Text ); 
end; 

procedure TForm1.LoginClick(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  //WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document ... ?? 
end;
```

Comment: There is not enough information. Are you trying to automated an external browser, or a browser embedded in your app? Or are you trying to interact with the web server programmably via an HTTP library?

Comment: thank you, I want to press the login button on the web,how  its complete code so I can login? i use twebbrowser component
This is the code that I wrote :

Comment: {$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.Open_webClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
webbrowser1.Navigate('https://v-tri.tri.co.id:8434/insms/dealer/en/loginin.do'); 
end;
procedure TForm1.InputClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('UserName').setAttribute('value', edit1.Text );
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('PassWord').setAttribute('value', edit2.Text );
end;
procedure TForm1.LoginClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
//WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document ... ??
end;
end.

Comment: Login to a certain web site is usually done by specifying `POST` related parameters in the `Navigate` method call. Nothing more. Usually :-)

Answer (score 2):

You already have code to locate and fill in the webform edit fields.  Use similar code to locate the element of the login button and call its `click()` method, or locate the element of the webform itself and call its `submit()` method.

Comment: Yesssss,,, It is PERFECT, Thank you all who have tried to give this solution, my respect for you, you are my best teacher.
  thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure TForm1.LoginClick(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
 WebBrowser1.oleobject.document.forms.item(0).submit(); 
end;
```

As @TLama already pointed out, you can skip all this and do a navigate to the login url with the postdata already attached. An example can be found [here](http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0139.htm).

Comment: "Doc.forms[0].submit();"
"[Error] Unit1.pas(44): Class does not have a default property"

I still have not found a solution, because I was just learning, I would greatly appreciate help you,  if you are willing compile the code for me
thanks , regards

Comment: Yesssss,,, It is PERFECT, Thank you all who have tried to give this solution, my respect for you, you are my best teacher.
  thank you

Comment: You don't have to thank me :) Just accept my answer (or Remy's) please

Comment: how the  next code for locate any element of the webform itself and implement at my program, because after a successful login, i get a new form. and the previous code(WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('').setAttribute('value', edit .Text );) can no longer be applied to my program.
 is there any other way to find all the elemnt on a web page? thank.

Comment: Short answer, you have to loop through the DOM elements. Please ask a new question and we will help you.

Comment: what the DOM elements.? What kind of example is :)

Comment: its core I would create a program to topup pulses Mobile phone, you should try to go to the web "https://v-tri.tri.co.id:8434/insms/dealer/en/loginin.do" by using
 username:"08989540330"
 and pasword: "@Gnt8a7u" 
Please I wait for your suggestions.

Comment: Please ask a new question?

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with logging into sites with TWebBrowser. I couldn't even log when i was actually pressing the Login Button with the mouse. I fixed the issue by replacing the TWebBrowser with Tchromium.