# How to fill any fields in a frame on twebbrowser?

Tags: delphi

After successfully logging on to web page "https://v-tri.tri.co.id:8434/insms/dealer/en/loginin.do", I get a new page consisting of three frames "https://v-tri.tri.co.id:8434/insms/dealer/en/Recharge.do?case.menuid=050116"

How to fill in the fields *located in the third frame* from my program (delphi7)?

[This is a continuation of the discussion "[Login to web using TWebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298196/login-to-web-using-twebbrowser)"]

I've tried this but it did not work:

```
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('fieldname').setAttribute('value', edit1.Text);
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('fieldname').setAttribute('value', edit2.Text);
```

Comment: This question looks like a repeat of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298196/login-to-web-using-twebbrowser but with less details - what am I missing?

Comment: @Flexo, this seems to be one step further. After login. But the principle will be the same.

Comment: yes, I need a solution to continue my program that has not finished, but I do not really know the next code, anyone who is willing to help sy would greatly appreciate the help of his 
if need a username and passwrd, i will give
thank you very much

Comment: You have to get the frame document

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.  You are simply not taking the frames into account.  The `OleObject.Document` represents the main window.  It has a `frames` collection, and each element in that collection has its own `contentDocument` object, eg:

```
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.frames.item(2).contentDocument.GetElementByID('fieldname').setAttribute('value', edit1.Text);
```

Comment: well, I have tried,  but have not managed i got a message error "Project raised exception class Vtri.exe EOleSysError with message 'Not Implemented'. process stopped.
sorry sir if I much asked,and if my english not good,i am sorry.  I was still a student :)

Comment: On which property exactly? Break up the statement into smaller assignments: `doc := ...OleObject.Document; frames := doc.frames; frame := frames.item(2);` and so on. Personally, I never use `TWebBrowser.OleObject`. I query `TWebBrowser.Document` for the `IHTMLDocument2` interface, and then access the DOM interfaces directly without involving `IDispatch` overhead.

Comment: I do not know about access to web pages with Delphi, I just wanted to fill in the textbox "MSISDN" and other field on the frame, no matter using any means, because I've been working very hard all these tasks from my school,   
and not getting results

Answer (score -2):

Answered already, this issue
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.Frames.Item (2). Document.getElementById ('id'). SetAttribute ('value', edit3.Text);
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.Frames.Item (2). Document.getElementById ('id'). SetAttribute ('value', '0 ');
thank all who have helped.